# How to write text file in java

Tags: java, filewriter

I am new to java and I am writing coding for automation in **Selenium**. I want to know is it possible to write a text file throughout the java program till end of the program. I have tried to write a text file using `bufferedWriter.write()`. First three lines are writing and after that it is not at all writing any text. I have tried flush.

My question is,do we have possibility to open file at starting of the program and write lines when ever we need in the middle of the program and as many number of lines and close the file end of the program?

If possible, request to share any same code. I am fine with any file write method `(File Writer, Buffered writer, file output stream)`

Comment: Did you `close()` and `flush()` it?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Did you even "try" to invest "any" time in "any" kind of research? [RTM](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=java+logging)

Comment: The question shouldn't be tagged Selenium as your question is only Java related. :-)

Comment: @UmaKanth I have close and flush

Comment: @Stefan I understand. I was new to programming when I ask this question also not aware many things

Comment: @Iridann Thanks for your suggestion. I was new to the programming language

Comment: @Dina I would recommend fixing the tags for future searchers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String filename="fileToRead.txt";
    FileWriter fw=null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);

        String text="";
        out.write(text);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//do stuff
//open streams again and write
```

true as parameter=>append mode:

```
fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
```

Comment: Would be worth actually explaining the flow to the OP, as it appears they didn't understand any of the examples out on the web.

Comment: @dskfdskjgds Thanks for the Code.